# Refresh a control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, paint, doevents

I am trying to change a link label's fore color but the color won't graphically change.

I have a timer that updates the fore color of the control

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyLbl.ForeColor = shouldUpdate? Color.Blue: Color.Gray;
    }
```

The update is successful and while debugging, I can see that the fore color property of myLbl is different. So why doesn't it change it graphically?

I also tried

```
MyLbl.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

And tried adding Application.DoEvents() after the change of the fore color.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike vanilla labels, link-labels don't use the `ForeColor` property in this manner to colour their text.

Use the [`LinkColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkcolor.aspx) property instead.

> Gets or sets the color used when displaying a normal link.

In your case, you need:

```
MyLbl.LinkColor = shouldUpdate? Color.Blue: Color.Gray;
```

Note that this *not* an update problem -  you don't have to explicitly call Application.DoEvents (which is almost never the right thing to do) or Invalidate or  Refresh to get the link-label to respond to the colour-change.

Comment: I missed the fact that it was a link label, and thought it may be a timer issue. Good catch!